# Can l use a wait(NULL) in fork()==0?

Tags: c, linux

Is possible to insert a wait(NULL) inside a child process, i mean when fork is equal to 0 it executes wait null.

Comment: Can you read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

Unless the child process forked itself to create another child process, it won't do any good and may create a zombie process.